# Fortran - avoid casting in a loop

Tags: casting, fortran

This problem always seems to come to me so I would like to know a better solution than what I currently do.
I want to build an array up using loops where the iteration parameter is used in the calculation.  The problem is that integers in the array index work fine, but lead to errors when used in calculations.  Perhaps an example of the problem would be useful.

```
DO ii = 1,N
ir = real(ii,kind=dp)  ! Cast this to real
DO ji=1,N
    jr = real(ji,kind=dp)  ! Cast this to real.
    IF (abs(sqrt((ir-1)**2 + (jr-1)**2)) < Lim) THEN
        A(ii,ji) = 1;
    ELSEIF (abs(sqrt((ir-1)**2 + (jr-N)**2)) < Lim) THEN
        A(ii,ji) = 1;
    ELSEIF (abs(sqrt((ir-N)**2 + (jr-1)**2)) < Lim) THEN
        A(ii,ji) = 1;
    ELSEIF (abs(sqrt((ir-N)**2 + (jr-N)**2)) < Lim) THEN
        A(ii,ji) = 1;
    END IF        
END DO
END DO
```

Is there a way to do this without casting to real every time through the loops?  I have a feeling this is a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that casting is a bottleneck, but you could try actually using reals and incrementing in the loops:

```
ri = 1.0
do ii=1,n
   rj = 1.0
   do jj=1,n
      ..math...
      rj = rj + 1.0
   enddo
   ri = ri + 1.0
enddo
```